# Serialize a List<T> content property to XAML without it being shown explicitly in the output

Tags: c#, xaml, serialization, collections, .net-4.0

I have a type like this:

```
// using System.Collections.Generic;
// using System.ComponentModel;
// using System.Windows.Markup;

[ContentProperty("Children")]
class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        this.Children = new List<Child>();
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

which I'd expect to be serialized by `XamlServices.Save` like this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
  ...
</Parent>
```

But I end up with something like this:

```
<Parent xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib">
  <scg:List ...>
    <Child />
    ...
  </scg:List>
</Parent>
```

I do not want to see `<scg:List>` in the XAML output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turns out to be very simple: declare the `Children` property setter `private` instead of `public`:

```
public List<Child> Children { get; private set; }
//                                 ^^^^^^^
//                                add this!
```

Everything else stays the same.